# Instruments in Xcode 4 Open GL Driver Tiler/Renderer Utilization Gone?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, xcode4

The OpenGL ES Driver Instrument in XCode 4 no longer has Tiler and Renderer Utilization, the two most useful statistics for measuring OpenGL ES bottlenecks. Did they get renamed? I noticed there are two new measurable stats, GPU Core Utilization and GPU Video Engine Utilization; do these now track tiling an rendering utilization, respectively?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the latest version of XCode (4.2) restored Tiler and Renderer Utilization to Instruments. I believe they were only missing during the initial release of XCode 4.